# Pass values to a trigger function in coffee script

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have some existing code where I want to make some changes.
Here it is calling a trigger function

```
$('table.fields tr:last').find('.options').trigger('click', [$this.data('id')])
```

and here is the function receiving two params,

```
$(document).on 'click', 'form .options', (event, time) ->
```

I have to pass another variable `index`

What I am trying is something like:

```
index = 1
$('table.fields tr:last').find('.options').trigger('click', [$this.data('id')], index)
```

And receiving like:

```
$(document).on 'click', 'form .options', (event, time, index) ->
  console.log index
```

but I am getting index `undefined` in function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass time params in array while Function call

```
$('table.fields tr:last').find('.options').trigger('click', [$this.data('id'), index])
```

Function defination will remain same as you are doing

```
$(document).on 'click', 'form .options', (event, time, index) ->
  console.log index
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want pass variables you have to use an array, like this

```
 .trigger( eventType [, extraParameters ] )

 .trigger('click', [$this.data('id'), index])
```